# xml to xml transformation through XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to convert one xml format to another xml format using XSLT .
Below is the input XML format that i need to transform to another XML format.

```
<FIXML>
    <Header>
        <RequestID>ReqID8942</RequestID>
        <RequestType>DocGen</RequestType>
        <Version>10.6</Version>
        <BankId>01</BankId>
        <ChannelId>LOS</ChannelId>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Data>
         <CorpAppLimitDetailsBO>
            <ApprovedLimitHomeCCY>100.0</ApprovedLimitHomeCCY>
            <ApprovedLimitCCY>INR</ApprovedLimitCCY>
            <ApprovedLimit>100.0</ApprovedLimit>
            <LimitClassification>ROOT</LimitClassification>
        <DBApplicantMiscDetails>
                    <APPLICANTMISCID>400000</APPLICANTMISCID>
                    <APPLICANTID>400030</APPLICANTID>
                    <MISCTYPE>APPLIED</MISCTYPE>
            </DBApplicantMiscDetails>
        </CorpAppLimitDetailsBO>
       </Data>
     </Body>
</FIXML>
```

Below is the output format xml which i expect.

```
<FIXML>
    <Header>
        <RequestID>ReqID8942</RequestID>
        <RequestType>DocGen</RequestType>
        <Version>10.6</Version>
        <BankId>01</BankId>
        <ChannelId>LOS</ChannelId>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Data>
            <LimitDetails>
            <Limit>
                <ApprovedLimitHomeCCY>100.0</ApprovedLimitHomeCCY>
                <ApprovedLimitCCY>INR</ApprovedLimitCCY>
                <ApprovedLimit>100.0</ApprovedLimit>
                <LimitClassification>ROOT</LimitClassification>
        <APPLICANTMISCID>400000</APPLICANTMISCID>
        <APPLICANTID>400030</APPLICANTID>
        <MISCTYPE>APPLIED</MISCTYPE>
            </Limit>
       </Data>
     </Body>
</FIXML>
```

I have tried with below code but dont know how to modify the code to inlcude DBApplicantMiscDetails details in output XML format.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="FIXML"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FIXML">
        <FIXML>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Header"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Body"/>
        </FIXML>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Body">
        <Body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Data"/>
        </Body>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Data>
            <LimitDetails>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="CorpAppLimitDetailsBO"/>
            </LimitDetails>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CorpAppLimitDetailsBO">
        <Limit>
            <xsl:copy-of select="child::*"/>
        </Limit>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is a slight mistake in your output XML, as there is no closing tag for `LimitDetails`. Also, you say you want to include `DBApplicantMiscDetails` but your sample XML looks like you want to remove it. Is this correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you could probably approach this is to build upon the XSLT identity transform, which on its own just copies the nodes in your XML

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You then add templates to match your special cases where you want to make changes (as opposed to written templates for elements you just want to copy). For example, to rename the **CorpAppLimitDetailsBO** to **Limit** you would do this

```
<xsl:template match="CorpAppLimitDetailsBO"> 
    <Limit> 
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </Limit> 
</xsl:template>
```

Removing the DBApplicationMiscDetails then becomes a straight-forward task

```
<xsl:template match="DBApplicantMiscDetails"> 
     <xsl:apply-templates /> 
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data"> 
        <Data> 
            <LimitDetails> 
                <xsl:apply-templates /> 
            </LimitDetails> 
        </Data> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CorpAppLimitDetailsBO"> 
        <Limit> 
            <xsl:apply-templates /> 
        </Limit> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="DBApplicantMiscDetails"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </xsl:template> 

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<FIXML>
   <Header>
      <RequestID>ReqID8942</RequestID>
      <RequestType>DocGen</RequestType>
      <Version>10.6</Version>
      <BankId>01</BankId>
      <ChannelId>LOS</ChannelId>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <Data>
         <LimitDetails>
            <Limit>
               <ApprovedLimitHomeCCY>100.0</ApprovedLimitHomeCCY>
               <ApprovedLimitCCY>INR</ApprovedLimitCCY>
               <ApprovedLimit>100.0</ApprovedLimit>
               <LimitClassification>ROOT</LimitClassification>
               <APPLICANTMISCID>400000</APPLICANTMISCID>
               <APPLICANTID>400030</APPLICANTID>
               <MISCTYPE>APPLIED</MISCTYPE>
            </Limit>
         </LimitDetails>
      </Data>
   </Body>
</FIXML>
```

Comment: Tim.Brillient.your answer reduced my effort lot.Thanks.I m getting some empty lines in the output xml.will it be possible to remove empty lines from output xml.

Comment: I am sure it will be possible, although you would need to define exactly what an 'empty line' is. Feel free to raise a new question if you can't manage to work it out.

Comment: Used <xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> to remove empty spaces/line.thanks